# Getting Sum of Multiple Columns and summing up values for the same id from a list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a list which returns.

```
Grade Col1 Col2  Col3  Col4
 t1   2    1      3     2
 t2   2    5      1     5
 t1   2    6      4     4
```

First, i need to add the values in each row for the corresponding Grade so that , i would have

```
Grade  Sum(Sum of the 4 columns)     
t1     8
t2     13
t1     16
```

and finally my result should be like:

```
Grade   Total
t1      8+16 = 24
t2       13
```

I'm a newbie to Linq., can someone suggest me the approach using Linq, for returning this result.??

Thanks

Comment: sorry, edited...!!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following LINQ query will group all rows by Grade and then produce sum of columns for each grade:

```
var query = from r in list
            group r by r.Grade into g
            select new {
               Grade = g.Key,
               Total = g.Sum(x => x.Col1 + x.Col2 + x.Col3 + x.Col4)
            };
```

Comment: does list has a ".Table" as its throwing me an exception there...!!

Comment: @sandy sorry, didn't notice you have list of objects. Thought you are doing query to database. Updated

Comment: works...!!! :) just a que...!! what if the Cols are also coming as a list and not separately...!!! like 
`List<string> ColValues..`???
Edit : I Have a List of the Col Property Coming in my Domain Model in my code...!!!

Comment: @sandy what you are expecting to get as total of strings? Concatenated strings?

Comment: No, it will be like Col[0] = 2, col[1] = 3...etc...as such which i bind in the grid...is there any way, that i can add them using the same query ..???

Comment: If there is strings containing integer values, you can parse them like this: `Total = g.SelectMany(x => x.ColValues).Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).Sum()`

Comment: works.. :).......
Last one... Just a thought..!! what if some of the cols have null, i mean no values...cuz dey take nullable values in db... 
If i fire this query, then i would get an exception, right..??
`"string was not in correct format"` , i think....??

Comment: @sandy you can add either `Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)` between `SelectMany` and `Select`. Or you can use following code for parsing: `Select(s => { int x; return Int32.TryParse(s, out x) ? x : 0)`

Comment: same functionality done, but used in a private method... Thanks :)...Got thru with ma work